# Can I condense an XPath expression that checks for conditional values of an attribute?

Tags: xpath

I have the following XML payload:

```
<fizz>
    <buzz class="foo">
        <whatever/>
    </buzz>
</fizz>
```

The value of the `/fizz/buzz[@class]/@class` attribute can be `foo`, `bar` or `whistlefeather`. I'm trying to write an efficient XPath expression that covers all three scenarios. The best I have is:

```
/fizz/buzz[@class]/@class = 'foo' |
    /fizz/buzz[@class]/@class = 'bar' |
    /fizz/buzz[@class]/@class = 'whistlefeather'
```

Is there some "shorthand" way to make this more condense/efficient (less verbose)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this (all xpath version) :

```
/fizz/buzz[@class='foo' or @class='bar' or @class='whistlefeather']
```

Using xpath >=2 :

```
/fizz/buzz[@class=("foo", "bar", "whistlefeather")]
```

Comment: I don't know why this has been accepted because it is plain wrong. You can't have a predicate in square brackets after the "/" operator.

Answer (score 0):

Correcting the answer from @GillesQuenot:

Using any XPath version:

```
/fizz/buzz[@class='foo' or @class='bar' or @class='whistlefeather']
```

Using XPath 2.0 or later:

```
/fizz/buzz[@class=("foo", "bar", "whistlefeather")]
```

(Note, this returns the selected `buzz` elements. It's unclear what you actually want the expression to return.)